# JavaScript modal getElementsByClassName

Tags: javascript, html, css, events

I'm building a modal based off of [w3s's tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modal_images.asp) however, instead of grabbing an "id" I need to grab multiple images with a "class" name instead. I used the classic for loop method then added a click function which does pop up with an empty box.

The problem is, although the box and background style appears the image is not showing up. Using an "id" on the target image + without the for loop works fine, shows up but adding a "class" with the loop does not. There's something I am missing in JS. Any help would be appreciated.

```js
let modal = document.getElementById("modal");
let imgs = document.getElementsByClassName("images");
let modalImg = document.getElementById("modal-img");

for (let i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
  imgs[i].addEventListener("click", () => {
    modal.style.display = "block";
    modalImg.src = this.src;
  });
}
```

```css
.images {
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}

.modal-content {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 700px;
}
```

```html
<!-- target images -->
<div>
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150?text=image1" alt="" class="images">
</div>
<div>
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150?text=image2" alt="" class="images">
</div>
<!-- modal -->
<div id="modal" class="modal">
  <img class="modal-content" id="modal-img">
</div>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please use placeholder.com or similar to add images in a [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An [Arrow function `() =>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) doesn't bind it's own `this` - You'll have to use standard function expression to bind `this` to the correct context ( The element in this case )

```js
let modal = document.getElementById("modal");
let imgs = document.getElementsByClassName("images");
let modalImg = document.getElementById("modal-img");

for (let i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
  imgs[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
    modal.style.display = "block";
    modalImg.src = this.src;
  });
}
```

```css
.images {
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}

.modal-content {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 700px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://placekitten.com/150?image=1" alt="" class="images">
</div>
<div>
  <img src="https://placekitten.com/150?image=2" alt="" class="images">
</div>

<div id="modal" class="modal">
  <img class="modal-content" id="modal-img">
</div>
```

Comment: Huge dupe.......

Comment: @Light This did the trick, thanks! I'll have to read up more on arrow functions